# Compute total from scanning string from left to right instead of right to left

Tags: java, oop, stack, arithmetic-expressions

I am basically trying to figure out a technique in which I can scan a string from left to right and it will give me the integer of it.
Starting from right to left is quiet easy as shown in the code below.
I am just struggling on finding a way to add each integer to make it the correct value it is supposed to be.

Output:
Would you like to enter an expression?
y
enter an expression
2567
value = 7652

I am trying to get the output to be in the correct order.

```
e = String input // string needing to be converted to double
p = 0 // position
// If a substring of e whose rightmost character is at position p
    // represents a number (possibly with a decimal point, possibly negative),
    // return the numerical value of the substring as a double value and
    // re-position p just to the left of the substring.

    private double formNum() {

        double total = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        double mult = 1;
        char c, d;
        do {
            c = e.charAt(p); // examine the current character in the string (from right to left)
            if (c == '.') {
                flag = 1; // set a flag to remember that the character is a decimal point
            } else {
                // if the current character is a digit, convert to its
                // int value and include it in the value corresponding to the string.
                if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
                    
                    total = total + mult * (c - '0');
                    mult = mult * 10.0;
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        count++; // count the number of digits to the right of a possible decimal point
                    }
                } else {
                    if (c == '(' && e.charAt(p + 1) == '-') {
                        total = -total; // an underscore character represents a negative value
                    }
                }
            }
            p++; // Prepare to move to the next character to the left.
                    // This is a private non-static method because it changes the member variable p
            d = '?';
            if (p <= e.length() - 1) {
                d = e.charAt(p); // the next character to the left
            }
        } while ((p <= e.length() - 1) && (((d <= '9') && (d >= '0')) || (d == '_') || (d == '.')));// check for a valid
                                                                                                    // character
        if (flag == 1) {
            total = total / Math.pow(10, count * 1.0); // compute the value taking into account
                                                        // the number of decimal places
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: You want to get the int value of a String, right?

Comment: yes correct, The code above gets turns a string into an int. Just trying to do the same process in the opposite direction

Comment: For example, your program takes 134.256 and returns 652.431, correct?

Comment: that is correct yes

Comment: @SWAGALERT9000 A general comment: Please add some sample input/output of your scenario. It is particularly helpful to understand the requirement of your problem. For example, by reading your post (without check the attached code), it is hard to understand that you need to handle floating point number for this problem.

Comment: @SWAGALERT9000 Besides, please share the code in a way so that people can try running it easily. For example, there is no variable declared as `e` and `p` in your attached code. I understand those are part of your class instance. It is an extra burden for someone who is not familiar with your code but wants to help you.

Comment: Have you heard of Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: Yes I have heard of Integer.parseInt()